# Grouping Fiscal year using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way in SQL Server that can show the Fiscal Year (begins on October 1 and ends on September 30) from a table which has a date column (1998 to 2010). Here is what I have done:

```
select 'FY1999' as FY, site, count(*)
from mytable
where mydate >='10/1/1998' 
    and mydate <'10/1/1999'
group by site
```

---

```
select 'FY2000' as FY, site, count(*)
from mytable
where mydate >='10/1/1999' 
    and mydate <'10/1/2000'
group by site
```

---

```
select 'FY2001' as FY, site, count(*)
from mytable
where mydate >='10/1/2000' 
    and mydate <'10/1/2001'
group by site
```

---

Isn't it too much repetitive when doing this for more then 10 FY year?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can even create your user-defined function in SQL Server that takes a date argument and returns the fiscal year as an int:

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetFiscalYear(@TheDate date)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @FiscalYear int  

    IF DATEPART(month, @TheDate) < 10
        SELECT @FiscalYear = DATEPART(year, @TheDate)
    ELSE
        SELECT @FiscalYear = DATEPART(year, @TheDate) + 1  

    RETURN @FiscalYear
END
```

Then you can use this as, for example:

```
SELECT Id, ShippingDate, GetFiscalYear(ShippingDate)
FROM SomeTable
```

Answer (score 11):

Here's a single query that will give you the information you want.

```
SELECT DATEPART(yyyy, DATEADD(mm, 3, mydate)) AS FY, site, COUNT(*) AS row_count
FROM mytable
GROUP BY DATEPART(yyyy, DATEADD(mm, 3, mydate)), site
```

Comment: Wow, I never thought to do that, what a good idea, that's so simple! I like this because it keeps the query self contained.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a bit repetitive. I'd be using DatePart and some easy to discern rules:

- Fiscal year is the year of the date if the month is < 10.
- Fiscal year is the year of the date + 1 if the month >= 10

Answer (score 1):

This is the dynamic script for UK, April to March,
for different dates you can use as refernece,

Good Luck

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME

SET @StartDate = DATEADD(dd,0, DATEDIFF(dd,0, DATEADD( mm, -(((12 + DATEPART(m, getDate())) - 4)%12), getDate() ) - datePart(d,DATEADD( mm, -(((12 + DATEPART(m, getDate())) - 4)%12),getDate() ))+1 ) )  

SET @EndDate = DATEADD(SS,-1,DATEADD(mm,12,@StartDate))

SELECT @StartDate,@EndDate
```

Answer (score 1):

Start of fiscal year:

```
DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, '20100401', getdate()) / 12 * 12, '20100401')
```

End of Fiscal Year

```
DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, '20100401', getdate()) / 12 * 12, '20110331')
```

Replace `getdate()` with your own date if required

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a SQL server reference handy, but here's how I'd do it in MySQL:

```
select date_format (date_add(mydate, interval 92 days), 'FY%Y') as FY, site, count(*)
 from mytable
 group by FY, site;
```

There are 92 days in October, November, and December, so I've offset by that much.

Comment: This is the same thing @bobs have in his answer below. The guy deserves  something not a downvote

Comment: @hiFI:  Thanks for pointing that out.  bobs' answer was given four hours after my answer.  Why aren't you hassling him?  Also, did you notice this answer is almost 9 years old?

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday there was an answer to this question, which was subsequently deleted.
I do not know why. Was there something wrong with it?

Please don't vote this answer down, I just want to know why it was deleted.

With vigorous testing, I still can't manage to fault it. In my example, Fiscal year starts July 1.

The answer was:

```
SELECT SUM(value), CAST(Year(DateAdd(Month, -6, TransactionDate)) as varchar) + ' - ' + CAST(Year(DateAdd(Month, 6, TransactionDate)) as varchar) as 'FY'
FROM          mytable
GROUP BY CAST(Year(DateAdd(Month, -6, mydate)) as varchar) + ' - ' + CAST(Year(DateAdd(Month, 6, mydate)) as varchar)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some test Sql based on Simon's answer

```
    DECLARE @basestartdate datetime, @baseenddate datetime
SET @basestartdate = CAST('1 April 1753' AS datetime)
SET @baseenddate = CAST('31 March 1754' AS datetime)

;
WITh TestData as
(
SELECT
    CAST('1 April 2015' AS datetime) input,
    CAST('1 April 2015' AS datetime) expectedstartdate,
    CAST('31 March 2016' AS datetime) expectedenddate UNION SELECT
    CAST('2 April 2015' AS datetime),
    CAST('1 April 2015' AS datetime),
    CAST('31 March 2016' AS datetime) UNION SELECT
    CAST('31 December 2015' AS datetime),
    CAST('1 April 2015' AS datetime),
    CAST('31 March 2016' AS datetime) UNION SELECT
    CAST('1 January 2016' AS datetime),
    CAST('1 April 2015' AS datetime),
    CAST('31 March 2016' AS datetime) UNION SELECT
    CAST('28 February 2016' AS datetime),
    CAST('1 April 2015' AS datetime),
    CAST('31 March 2016' AS datetime) UNION SELECT
    CAST('31 March 2016' AS datetime),
    CAST('1 April 2015' AS datetime),
    CAST('31 March 2016' AS datetime) UNION SELECT
    CAST('1 April 2016' AS datetime),
    CAST('1 April 2016' AS datetime),
    CAST('31 March 2017' AS datetime)
),
Results AS
(
SELECT
    input,
    expectedstartdate,
    DATEADD(MONTH, 
            12 * (DATEDIFF(MONTH, @basestartdate, input) / 12),
            @basestartdate) startdate,
    expectedenddate,
    DATEADD(MONTH, 
            12 * (DATEDIFF(MONTH, @basestartdate, input) / 12),
            @baseenddate) enddate
FROM testdata
)
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN (expectedstartdate = startdate) THEN 'Pass' ELSE 'Fail'
    END startdateresult,
    CASE
        WHEN (expectedenddate = enddate) THEN 'Pass' ELSE 'Fail'
    END startdateresult
FROM results
ORDER BY input
```